# Bad Credentials for Github API

Tags: git, bash, curl, github, github-api

I have the following script, which I am trying to test out in bash, using curl to do a couple things, one is to create a new repo, the second - which is not implemented yet - is to get the git_url from the json thats returned, which I'm not sure if my `parse_json` function will let me do that and then finally to push a sample commit message to that repo.

the script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux

# Json Function: parse_json 'json string' key
function parse_json()
{
    echo $1 | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -F=':' -v RS=',' "\$1~/\"$2\"/ {print}" | sed -e "s/\"$2\"://" | tr -d "\n\t" | sed -e 's/\\"/"/g' | sed -e 's/\\\\/\\/g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//g' | sed -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//'
}

git_create_repo() {
    read -e -p  "Please enter your API Key: " apiKey
    read -e -p  "Repo Name: " repoName
    read -e -p  "Repo Description: " repoDescription

    # Use the API to create a a repository
    response=$(curl -i -H 'Authorization: token $apiKey' \
        -d '{ \
                "name": "$repoName", \
                "description": "$repoDescription", \
                "private": false, \
                "license_template": "mit" \
            }' \
        https://api.github.com/AdamKyle/repos)

    echo $response
}

git_create_repo
```

When I go through all the steps I get:

```
{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I am wondering if its because of the way I am putting in my api key with: `curl -i -H 'Authorization: token $apiKey ...'` I have tried `"$apiKey"` but even that doesn't work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it this way:

```
curl -X 'POST' -u $MY_AUTH https://api.github.com/...
```

where $MY_AUTH was generated in github website. It looks like:

```
export MY_AUTH="...hash...:x-oauth-basic"
```

Comment: can you give me more of a complete example, im not following.

Comment: I use this command to clone a repository: `curl -X 'POST' -u $MY_AUTH https://api.github.com/repos/$UPSTREAM_USER/$UPSTREAM_REPOSITORY/forks`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue.
Strangely using **double-quotes** instead of single-quotes for the headers solved the issue for me. Like below :

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token $apiKey" ....
```

Comment: Normal: single-quoted `echo '$MY_VAR'` prints `$MY_VAR`, while double-quoted `echo "$MY_VAR"` prints its value `42`. Single quotes mean **do not** treat `$` specially, this is just plain text. If you want your variable to get substituted in your command argument, you need to use double quotes.