# How to access the github API via requests in python?

Tags: python, github, python-requests

I am trying to access the github API via requests with python (Answers in similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622439/how-to-use-github-api-token-in-python-for-requesting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669504/bad-credentials-for-github-api) do not help).

Using curl, I am able to get a list of recent commits for a project, e.g.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json Authorization: token a0d42faabef23ab5b5462394373fc133ca107890" https://api.github.com/repos/rsapkf/42/commit
```

Trying to use the same setup in python with requests I tried to use

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/rsapkf/42/commits"
headers = {"Accept": "application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json", "Authorization": "token a0d42faabef23ab5b5462394373fc133ca107890"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

as well as

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/rsapkf/42/commits"
headers = {"Accept": "application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json"}
my_username = "someuser"
my_token  = "a0d42faabef23ab5b5462394373fc133ca107890"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=(my_username, my_token))
```

but in both cases I get the response

```
{'documentation_url': 'https://docs.github.com/rest',
 'message': 'Bad credentials'}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: shameless plug: I wrote a package that makes using github API easier: https://cmustrudel.github.io/strudel.scraper/

Comment: @Marat Thank you for that suggestion, but it does not seem to work. I get an error `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url...`

Comment: You must not give a token, then it works !?!

Comment: for certain APIs, e.g. to read from private repositories you have access to, you have to use auth. Also, even for public data, unauthenticated requests are limited to only 60/hour per IP

Answer (score 0):

No Authentication is required. The following works:

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/rsapkf/42/commits"
headers = {"Accept": "application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: it only gives you 60 requests per hour. The problem in the original code was that `my_username` should be `token` instead of `someuser`